# Creating a numerical variable order

Tags: r, variables, numerical

I have a set of data with 3 columns: index column (with no name), colour, colour of seed, and germination time.

How do I create a numerical variable called 'order' with values 1 to 22 (the number of data sets)?

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if I get you right, but simplest way would be:

```
> order <- c(1:22)
> order
 [1]  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20 21 22
```

No, if you run:

```
class(order)
```

you will get:

```
[1] "integer"
```

but you can easily get every element of object order (especially in a loop)

```
for(i in 1:length(order)){
print(order[i])
}
```

Comment: Does that turn 'order' into a variable though?

Comment: I've just tried using 'order' as part of a new ANOVA table and it won't work. So I'm guessing 'order' isn't a variable using those commands above

Comment: Watch out for using your variables name same as some functions, they can mismatch or misinterpret your code, see ?order -> it is a function!